# Android simulators in visual studio for mac

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I installed visual studio for mac and developing xamarin based applications for ios and android.

I see all iphone simulators for ios but for android I do not see all simulators. I only see two simulators for android.

How can I add more android simulators to test my application on various devices?

Answer (score 0):

For Android, you will need to create your google emulators manually. You can follow below steps to do that:

1. Install android platforms android emulator system image in `Tools->SDK Manager`:

[image]

2. Then open `Tools->Google Emulator Manager` and create a new Emulator for android:

[image]

3. You can open this emulator in your visual studio now:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use Visual Studio Code? Android Studio is a free software and you can download the emulators for a wide variety of android phones. If you aren't already using Android Studio I would give that a try if you are developing android apps. Here is the URL for Android Studio https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
Cheers,
Rachel